# "Can not connect to Docker Daemon"

Tags: docker

I have a project in which I need to use CircleCi to build a docker application image, and then upload it to the Amazon container repository.

Given that CircleCI also runs on Docker, I created a Docker image for it, which containers a version of Ubuntu, together with AWS CLI, Node and Docker. See Dockerfile below:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# update libraries
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"

# install docker
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-cache policy docker-ce
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce
                                   # <---
RUN systemctl status docker        # <--- TROUBLE HERE
                                   # <---
# install node
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN apt install -y nodejs 

# install aws cli
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential  
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install awscli --upgrade
```

I am currently having some problems working with this CircleCi docker image, because, if i keep the command `RUN systemctl status docker` I get the following error:

`Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory The command '/bin/sh -c systemctl status docker' returned a non-zero code: 1`

If, on the other, I remove that command, the build is sucessful. However, when I go inside docker `sudo docker run -it unad16` and run any docker command, as, f.e., `docker images`, I get the  following error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I have been trying to debug this error since yesterday, but have been unsucessfull. Thus, any help would be truly appreciated.

Notes:

- the "daemon" error occurs even when I run docker in priviled mode with `sudo docker run -ti  --privileged=true unad16`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to run a docker daemon if you want to build a docker image in circleci. Instead you just need an image with docker client, and a circle config with `- setup_remote_docker`.

Read more in
https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/building-docker-images/

If for some other reason you still want to run a docker service in a docker image, please refer to [DockerInDocker](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind) repo, especially the README.md part.

Comment: This was very useful, thank you. I have a follow up question, maybe you can also help me with that. Even when using "setup_remote_docker", you still must pass it a Docker image that contains the relevant commands, including Docker, correct? F.e., when you pass a Docker image with only Node.Js, and it tries to run the docker build commands, it will throw an error saying "docker not found"

Comment: Yes, you need a docker client in your image to connect to the remote docker, but you don't need to run the actual daemon service.

Comment: Great, thank you for your help, I will accept the answer as it solved the problem. Cheers.